# Show: could not combine graphic objects

Tags: plotting, graphics

I read `Show`'s documentation but couldn't understand why it fails. Here's the relevant code:

```
(* graphics *)
profile := ParametricPlot[beta[t], {t, 0, Evaluate[Roll[4*length1, B]][[1]]},
    PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False, Background -> GrayLevel[0.9]];
gen[s_] := ParametricPlot[Evaluate[ff[t, s]], {t, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> All,
    PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.005], Darker[Green]}}, Axes -> False,
    Background -> GrayLevel[0.9]];
trajectory := Evaluate[ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Roll[s, B]], {s, 0, 2*length1},
    PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.008], Purple}},
    Axes -> False, Background -> GrayLevel[0.9], PlotPoints -> 100]];
contactPoint[s_] := Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.025], Point[beta[s]]}];
trajectoryPoint[s_] := Graphics[{Purple, PointSize[0.025], Point[Roll[s, B]]}];

FG[s_] := Show[trajectory, gen[s], trajectoryPoint[s], profile,
    contactPoint[s], PlotRange -> {{-b1, 2*length1 + b1}, {-0.6, 2*b1 + 0.6}},
    ImageSize -> {300, 300}];
Animate[FG[s], {s, 0, 2*length1}]
```

The functions used in this code (`beta`, `Roll`, etc.) work, and I can see that by plotting the single elements. However, when combining them with `Show`, this is the result:
[image: show]

If I draw a single frame, this is the result:
[image: show2]

I searched extensively for these errors, but couldn't find anything relevant:

```
Ignoring invalid graphics directive Opacity[Skeleton[1]].
Ignoring invalid graphics directive Opacity[Skeleton[1]].
Coordinate {Skeleton[2]} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.
```

I think the problem has to do with the different graphic objects having different coordinates. Is that why it cannot combine them? I find the errors to be really cryptic.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6AOgfrRDZVSTl9YRHpJWWdZb1k/view?usp=sharing) is a notebook reproducing the problem. I am using Mathematica 11.

Comment: Please provide all definitions needed to reproduce the problem

Comment: @Kuba The code is pretty long, I'll have to provide the whole notebook.

Comment: Skeleton[1] seems to be the problem. Not the right input for Opacity.

Comment: No you won't. Please reduce the code to the minimal working example. Drop all parts that are not needed to recreate the problem. E.g. it seems only the first arg in Show is enough to show it.

Comment: Aren't you using `Short` or `Shallow` somewhere?

Comment: @Kuba I've attached the notebook. I'll work to reduce it to a minimal example. In the meantime, if someone's interested they can run it. No `Short` or `Shallow` usage in my notebook.

Comment: The only way to solve this problem is to construct a minimal example. Surely, it is not that hard to isolate the problem. You just keep removing pieces from the code until the problem disappears, to identify where it is.  Why didn't you do this instead of posting the whole notebook?  You have `Show[a,b,c,d,e...]`: then try removing `a` first, is there problem there?  Yes?  Then remove `b` too, etc.   Find which one is "bad".  Expand function definitions. Look at the options in Show, remove them. This is something that *you* can do easily. Do it next time.

Comment: Anyway, the problem is that in `Show`, you have a `\[RightArrow]` after `PlotRange` instead of a `\[Rule]`.  Maybe you copied this from somewhere or entered it in a non-standard way.  Rules are entered as `->`, i.e. dash-greater.

Comment: Another thing: please *always* show us the same code that causes the error, and *always* try running the code that you post here.  What you posted here did not have a `\[RightArrow]`, it has a `->`.

Answer (score 1):

Show is unable to combine the Options for some reason. Workaround is to provide the options with the first Graphics Object (trajectory):

```
profile := 
  ParametricPlot[\[Beta][t], {t, 0, 
  Evaluate[Roll[4*length1, B]][[1]]}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Axes -> False, Background -> GrayLevel[0.9]];
gen[s_] := 
  ParametricPlot[Evaluate[ff[t, s]], {t, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.005], Darker[Green]}}, Axes -> False, 
  Background -> GrayLevel[0.9]];
trajectory := 
  Evaluate[ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Roll[s, B]], {s, 0, 2*length1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.008], Purple}}, Axes -> False, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, ImageSize -> {300, 300}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-b1, 2*length1 + b1}, {-0.6, 2*b1 + 0.6}}]];
contactPoint[s_] := 
  Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.025], Point[\[Beta][s]]}, 
  Background -> GrayLevel[0.9]];
trajectoryPoint[s_] := 
  Graphics[{Purple, PointSize[0.025], Point[Roll[s, B]]}, 
  Background -> GrayLevel[0.9]];
FG[s_] := 
  Show[trajectory, gen[s], trajectoryPoint[s], profile, 
  contactPoint[s]];
Animate[FG[s], {s, 0, 2*length1}]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. This workaround is totally acceptable, but I find it very odd that Mathematica's errors didn't really address the options.